# return all the value between two decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have two values which has decimal(15,2) datatypes

eg.

```
@from='19.99'
```

and

```
 @to='20.02'
```

i have to return the range between that two value

expected output-`19.99, 20.00, 20.01, 20.02`

Answer (score 4):

you can use Tally/Number approach on this like below

```
DECLARE @from DECIMAL(10,2) , @to DECIMAL(10,2), @interval DECIMAL(10,2)

SET @from=19.99
SET @to= 20.02
SET @interval=0.01
SELECT @from +r*@interval 
FROM
(
SELECT TOP (SELECT CAST((@to-@from)/@interval AS INT)+1)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -1  r
FROM 
sys.objects s1 CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
)T
```

<kbd>**[Working demo](http://rextester.com/EBD6873)**</kbd>

Comment: Msg 1060, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
The number of rows in the TOP clause must be an integer.

Comment: @Thebeginner updated.

Comment: this works but can we simplified this query?

Comment: @Thebeginner Recommended reading http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: there are any function or method for this?

Comment: @Thebeginner Please note that this answer is `You can also do something similar with a "numbers" table` that Gordon spoke about in his answer and is better and efficient than the WHILE loop

Comment: This technique will be the fastest solution posted by far. It will be much faster than the loop or recurive cte solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE @From DECIMAL (15,2) = 19.99;
DECLARE @To DECIMAL (15,2) = 20.02;
DECLARE @Step DECIMAL (15,2) = 00.01;
DECLARE @R TABLE (Value DECIMAL(15,2));

WHILE @From <= @To
    begin
        INSERT INTO @R VALUES (@From);
        SET @From = @From + @Step;
    End
SELECT *
FROM @R;
```

Result:

```
+=======+
| Value |
+=======+
| 19,99 |
+-------+
| 20,00 |
+-------+
| 20,01 |
+-------+
| 20,02 |
+-------+
```

Using a `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @From DECIMAL (15,2) = 19.99;
DECLARE @To DECIMAL (15,2) = 20.02;
DECLARE @Step DECIMAL (15,2) = 00.01;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT @Step * 1 Val
        UNION ALL
    SELECT @Step * 2
        UNION ALL
    SELECT @Step * 3
        UNION ALL
    SELECT @Step * 4
    )
  SELECT @From - @Step + CTE.Val Value FROM CTE;
```

Result:

```
+=======+
| Value |
+=======+
| 19,99 |
+-------+
| 20,00 |
+-------+
| 20,01 |
+-------+
| 20,02 |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select @from as val
      union all
      select cast(val + 0.01 as decimal(15,2))
      from cte
      where density < @to
     )
select val
from cte
option (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Note: If you have more than 100 rows to insert, you will need to explore the max recursion option.

You can also do something similar with a "numbers" table.

Comment: The numbers table approach is tge wsy to go. Using recursive CTEs for counting lile this is terribly innificient. Note tgis article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: is that possible with only simple query?

Comment: not return proper result when my from is greater the to

Comment: how to use max recursion option.